# Localizing a XIB, different method on Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, xib

On previous versions of Xcode, when you localized a XIB it would create copies of that XIB on the language folders. Now, when you do the same thing, Xcode created localized strings for every language.

My question is: will this method work on iOS 7 if I compile my target for that version or will this just work for iOS 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will most likely work but there's a few cases where it won't.

`A storyboard or XIB will not localize correctly if all of the following three conditions are true:
The storyboard or XIB uses size classes.
The base localization and the build target are set to Universal.
The build targets iOS 7.0.`

(details in the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Xcode_Release_Notes.pdf) page 32)

Comment: Wow. Someone at Apple is crazy and needs regular electroshock sessions! WTF! What happened with "it just works"? Thanks for the information!!!

Comment: So the most logical fix here is to turn off size classes? That seems crazy.